Python: Tensorflow2 CNN + shap + GradientExplainer returns KeyError "Exception encountered when calling Functional.call()"
I want to evaluate individual layers of a convolutional neural network using GradientExplainer from shap. I am using Tensorflow2 2.16.1 and shap 0.45.00.
When trying to obtain the shap values, I obtain a Key Error with a (at least for me) cryptic error message:
KeyError: "Exception encountered when calling Functional.call().\n\n\x1b[1m2313030926784\x1b[0m\n\nArguments received by Functional.call():\n  • inputs=['tf.Tensor(shape=(9, 12, 12, 16), dtype=float32)']\n  • training=None\n  • mask=['None']"

Any help would be appreciated.
As an example I am using the mnist database:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

from tqdm.keras import TqdmCallback

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2 as cv

import shap

# Normalize the data
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

#x_train, x_test = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1) / 255.0, np.expand_dims(a=x_test, axis=-1) / 255.0
x_train = x_train.reshape((-1,28,28,1)).astype('float32') / 255.0
x_test = x_test.reshape((-1,28,28,1)).astype('float32') / 255.0

# Obtaining possible labels from the dataset
labels = np.unique(ar=y_test)

# Define sequential model.
modelCNN = tf.keras.Sequential()

# Add first convolutional layer.
modelCNN.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, input_shape=(28,28,1),
kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))

# Add second convolutional layer.
modelCNN.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16,
kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))

modelCNN.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

modelCNN.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,
kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'))

modelCNN.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

# Flatten feature maps.
modelCNN.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())

# Define output layer.
modelCNN.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))

# check for other activiations and other loss function

modelCNN.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(modelCNN.summary())

# Train the model.
modelCNN.fit(x_train, y_train, 
             epochs=1, 
             verbose=0, callbacks=[TqdmCallback(verbose=1)])

# Evaluate the model
loss, accuracy = modelCNN.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(f"Test Accuracy: {accuracy * 100:.2f}%")

# 1st 9 images
x_test_shap =x_test[0:9]
y_test_shap = y_test[0:9]

# Evaulate 3rd layer

layer_index = 3

model_input = tf.keras.Model(inputs=modelCNN.layers[0].input, 
                        outputs=modelCNN.layers[layer_index - 1].output)

model_output = tf.keras.Model(inputs=modelCNN.layers[layer_index].input, 
                         outputs=modelCNN.layers[-1].output

gradient_explainer = shap.GradientExplainer(model_output, model_input.predict(x_test))

This all works, but when I want to calculate the shap values of gradient_explainer with
gradient_explainer.shap_values(X=model_input.predict(x_test_shap),ranked_outputs=2,nsamples=9,return_variances=True,rseed=123)

I obtain the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_1808\2850607786.py in <module>
      8 print(v.dtype)
      9 
---> 10 gradient_explainer.shap_values(model_input.predict(x_test_shap),ranked_outputs=2,nsamples=9,return_variances=True,rseed=123)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shap\explainers\_gradient.py in shap_values(self, X, nsamples, ranked_outputs, output_rank_order, rseed, return_variances)
    156 
    157         """
--> 158         return self.explainer.shap_values(X, nsamples, ranked_outputs, output_rank_order, rseed, return_variances)
    159 
    160 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shap\explainers\_gradient.py in shap_values(self, X, nsamples, ranked_outputs, output_rank_order, rseed, return_variances)
    266             model_output_values = self.run(self.model_output, self.model_inputs, X)
    267         else:
--> 268             model_output_values = self.run(self.model, self.model_inputs, X)
    269         if ranked_outputs is not None and self.multi_output:
    270             if output_rank_order == "max":

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shap\explainers\_gradient.py in run(self, out, model_inputs, X)
    393                 v = tf.constant(X[i].reshape(shape), dtype=self.model_inputs[i].dtype)
    394                 inputs.append(v)
--> 395             return out(inputs)
    396 
    397 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    120             # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121             # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123         finally:
    124             del filtered_tb

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\src\ops\function.py in _run_through_graph(self, inputs, operation_fn)
    157         output_tensors = []
    158         for x in self.outputs:
--> 159             output_tensors.append(tensor_dict[id(x)])
    160 
    161         return tree.pack_sequence_as(self._outputs_struct, output_tensors)

KeyError: "Exception encountered when calling Functional.call().\n\n\x1b[1m2313030926784\x1b[0m\n\nArguments received by Functional.call():\n  • inputs=['tf.Tensor(shape=(9, 12, 12, 16), dtype=float32)']\n  • training=None\n  • mask=['None']"

